# How do I configure Diablo 2 in Wine to -skiptobnet and -w?

Tags: diablo-ii, wine

I am using Ubuntu Gnome and Diablo 2 works ok with Wine. How do I add shortcut options to the game? I want the -skiptobnet and -w for windowed mode.
Path is ~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/Diablo II/Game.exe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get options to work using the windows `.lnk` file that was created in the wine start menu directory during installation.

You can launch Diablo II through terminal or create a new launcher using this command replacing **PATH_TO_WINE** and **PATH_TO_SHORTCUT**:

```
env WINEPREFIX="PATH_TO_WINE" wine C:\\windows\\command\\start.exe PATH_TO_SHORTCUT -skiptobnet -w
```

For example:

```
env WINEPREFIX="/home/nonterrorist/.wine" wine C:\\windows\\command\\start.exe /Unix /home/nonterrorist/.wine/dosdevices/c:/users/Public/Start\ Menu/Programs/Diablo\ II/Diablo\ II\ -\ Lord\ of\ Destruction.lnk -skiptobnet -w
```

**Note** in the example above, you will need to escape any spaces in the shortcut path using `\`